# Node.js + Socket.IO websockets under heavy load

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Have been developing a real time app using Node.js + Socket.IO for a few years now, with a fairly large amount of real time messaging (~200K msgs sent/day).  It appears we have hit a new load threshold where for some reason the websockets connection in Chrome for some users is falling back to interval polling (jsonp, xhr), even though the browser supports websockets.  Need to profile latency on the node event loop next, but currently peaking around 2,600 concurrent socket.io connections with netstat cmds.

Any ideas why the websockets connection is falling back to interval polling?  We're also seeing some socket.io timeouts, connection refused, at peak load times.  But CPU on the server is reasonable (peak 25% on node process, 45% overall, and there is plenty of memory free on the server as well.

My current theory is there is some latency in the node event loop, that is backing up the socket connections.  To reduce load, I'm considering adding more broadcast emit rooms to further reduce the total messages sent/received.

Any other thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Are you utilizing a large amount of nested callbacks? I've been experiencing a similar issue with significantly less load than you and I've found switching to promises has helped with performance as well.

Comment: Not deeply nested, just 5 main methods like this...
socket.on('customMessage', function (data) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('customMessageResponse', data);
    });

Comment: Which I'm converting to something like this...
socket.broadcast.to(data.Room).emit('publishMessageToRoom', data);

Comment: FYI, broadcast emit won't really help you.  It is still sending individual messages to each and every socket in the room.  Rooms are merely a means of keeping track of a collection of sockets and then offering the ability to send a message to each and every individual socket.

Comment: Can you watch the network tab in a browser client when it fails to use a webSocket connection and see what the initial exchange with the server looks like?  It seems that you want to see if the server is failing to offer the upgrade to webSocket, if there's an error or if it is timing out or what?

Comment: Thanks guys!  Four of my five main node server methods currently broadcast to every socket.  I'm working on limiting these broadcasts to just the socket members in each room. That should reduce the total messages sent, and total received.  I have one other broadcast method that does this and works well.

Comment: After a certain point, on some of these connections during peak load, it says switching protocols to wss... tries for a while, and then receives the error  ERR_TIMED_OUT or ERR Connection Refused.   If it just times out, then it falls back to interval polling.  And never tries to upgrade to websockets again during that session.  Have to try new tab, or close/reopen browser to get it to try websockets again.

Comment: Your server is not responding before the client timeout value awaiting a response, likely because your server is momentarily too busy.  You can either figure out how to make the server less busy (the best option), move to clustering so you have more server processes to serve your requests (probably means you have to move to redis to share state too) or increase the client timeout.  Probably best to use a combination of these.

Comment: Yeah, the challenge here is determining what exactly is too busy.  CPU and Memory look healthy.  I could add clustering next, but it's tough to validate you've solved the problem without being able to identify and quantify the root cause.  Any thoughts as to what to hone in on?